# Streaming data server to client into list view and Drag and Drop to Client

Tags: asp.net, wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

i created wpf project
it has a listbox item in D: Drive file when i select one or multiple file

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        List<string> file = new List<string>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            file.Add(@"D:\file1.txt");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder1");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder2");
            file.Add(@"D:\folder3");
            lstTest.DataContext = file;
        }


        private Point start;
        private void lstTest_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.start = e.GetPosition(null);
        }

        private void lstTest_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point mpos = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = this.start - mpos;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance && Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                if (this.lstTest.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                string[] Files = new string[file.Count] ;
                for (int i = 0; i < file.Count; i++)
                {
                    Files[i] = file[i];
                }
                string dataFormat = DataFormats.FileDrop;
                DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(dataFormat, (lstTest.SelectedItems.Cast<string>()).ToArray<string>());
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }
    }
```

and i can drag and drop this file into my pc or desktop it work really good
it stored file or folder in my physical file 
but,my boss says that  server data or file are list in listview and download them and drag and drop to the pc
pls if any idea or suggestion pls let me know!

Comment: @please any one who know how to list the item in server file